# What is the best way to backup an SSH key in case my hard drive fails, etc?

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, sftp, root

I have disabled root user login for my CentOS server running cPanel. This is frustrating, as I then cannot login via SFTP and get to my root files on my server to check error logs (which I frequently have to do).

So I decided to just re-enable root login and set up SSH as it seems that this is very secure, but it seems this will create a key on my computer that once lost, I will not be able to retrieve, and could possibly lock me out of my own server forever (I may be mistaken on this).

So if that's the case, I would need a way to back up my keys on a flash drive or a Dropbox or something. This way if I reinstall Windows (which I do all the time because it's fun) or lose my data somehow, I can just get back to work without a workaround, if there even is one.

:)

Comment: I use various cloud services and sync a Bitlocker encrypted VHDD, and use Acronis to schedule backups of the VHDD

Comment: You might want to consider storing the key on multiple computers.  For that matter, you might want to consider making multiple keys work.  That way, if you're ever editing the text file and accidentally corrupt one line or maybe cosmic radiation alters one bit for you, you can still get in.  Worst case scenario should be that you can probably break into the machine if you have console access (which you probably should have, even remotely, if this is a virtual machine you manage), so this might be worthwhile to back up but not quite as critical as you've been imagining.

Answer (score 2):

What is the format of the key you have?

If it is a using the OpenSSH format (and not putty) then it is probably a plain text file.  Just copy the text into a secure note in bitwarden, lastpass or whatever password manager you use.  If key is in some binary format, you could just base64 encode it and store it somewhere.

Heck, you could print it out. If you wanted to make it easy to type, you could make a QR encoded version of it. ED25519 keys are both secure, and pretty short, and should easily fit on a card you can carry in a wallet.

If you do choose to store a copy on the cloud, you should be certain that you have set a strong pass-phrase on the key so that it is encrypted.

Comment: Yup.  Pretty much any way to back things up can work.